# can you cache a view using animation blocks

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

Is there an equivalent way of doing this using animation blocks

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:<some_transition> forView:<view> cache:YES];
```

this seemed to be handy way of not getting staggered animations or to make animations smooth so it doesn't keep redrawing every so often.   But i can't seem to figure out how to do this with animation blocks.  Maybe i've just missed something somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the block based methods for transitions: `+[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:]` and `+[UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]`.

The views are by default cached when you use these block based methods. You turn caching of using the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option.

Answer (score 1):

The option only makes sense for transitions. Most animations that you'd use an animation block for couldn't make use of a rasterized cache of just one entire view, because they involve multiple views that move relative to one another and must be composited in every frame of the animation.